# Normal Query to Prepared Statement

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm currently working with databases etc. And on one page my code looks like this. I know how to do prepared statement, but just can't figure out (in my head) how to change this query and what to put in bind_param and bind_result etc.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
$topDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(ends, starts) as datedifference FROM news WHERE DATEDIFF(starts,'$topDate')>0 ORDER BY starts LIMIT 12;";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //What i do with my data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for using prepared statements.

Here is an example of your code as a prepared statement (bear in mind that I don't know what you're table structure looks like):

```
$connection = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT *, DATEDIFF(ends, starts) as datedifference FROM news WHERE DATEDIFF(starts,?)>0 ORDER BY starts LIMIT 12;");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $topDate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4) //...etc, the number of variables here must match the column count;
if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        print("col1 = " . $col1, "col2 = " . $col2,"col3 = " . $col3,"col4 = " . $col4);
        //will bind the rows results to the $col variables on every pass.
    }



}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for this :). Looks correct, i'll let you know if it works once i test it out.